# Importación desde el directorio raíz

Tags: python, flask

me encuentro en el desarrollo de una app con Flask, el problema es que no estoy puedo realizar una importación desde el directorio raíz. Esta es una imagen del problema que tengo con la estructura del proyecto.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ya intente haciéndolo con `from ...app import db, ma`, pero con esto me da el siguiente error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "run.py", line 3, in <module>
    from app import db
  File "/mnt/c/users/leona/documents/Pirotech/app.py", line 5, in <module>
    from resources.Clientes.views import Cliente
  File "/mnt/c/users/leona/documents/Pirotech/resources/Clientes/views.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .model import Cliente, ClienteSchema
  File "/mnt/c/users/leona/documents/Pirotech/resources/Clientes/model.py", line 1, in <module>
    from ...app import db, ma
ValueError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package
```

Comment: ¿`db` dónde se define? Parece que tienes un problema de `import` circular o no estás definiendo correctamente `db` pero sin ver el código completo es difícil de comentar.

Comment: `db` esta definido en el archivo app.py que se encuentra en la raiz del proyecto de esta forma: 
`from flask import Blueprint
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_marshmallow import Marshmallow
from flask_restful import Api
from resources.Clientes.views import Cliente

db = SQLAlchemy()
ma = Marshmallow()

api_bp = Blueprint('api', __name__)
api = Api(api_bp)

# Route
api.add_resource(Cliente, '/cliente')`

Comment: Quizá debas instanciar `db` antes de hacer este `import` -> `from resources.Clientes.views import Cliente` pero sin ver el código completo no te puedo ayudar mejor.

Comment: Seguro que `app.py` esta en la raíz? me parece que esta dentro de la carpeta `resources`. Prueba con `from resources.app import db`.

Comment: si `app.py` esta al mismo nivel que `resources` Comparto el link del repositorio para que puedan ver la estructura de todo el proyecto https://github.com/leonardoAlonso/Pirotech